# Share embedded youtube video to facebook & google+

Tags: facebook, video, youtube, share

Here is the scenario, I have an embedded youtube video on the page and 2 share buttons below it; the client wants those buttons to share the embedded video. This is a pretty straight forward question... just not sure how to go about it.

I understand that the video has sharing buttons, but they want the two big buttons outside of the iframe to share the video.

Answer (score 0):

Give the same OG Metatags as given by youtube for that page.

For example if you have embedded this video on the page "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkN7P08_oYM", then see the page source and mention the metatags as given on that page like

```
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkN7P08_oYM">
<meta property="og:title" content="The Mysteries of Laura NBC Official Trailer [HD] | THE MYSTERIES OF LAURA">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MkN7P08_oYM/maxresdefault.jpg">

  <meta property="og:description" content="The Mysteries of Laura NBC Official Trailer: Get a look at the new series The Mysteries of Laura coming to NBC Wednesdays this fall. » Subscribe: http://bit....">

<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="544007664">
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="YouTube">
  <meta property="al:ios:url" content="vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkN7P08_oYM&amp;feature=applinks">
<meta property="al:android:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkN7P08_oYM&amp;feature=applinks">
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="YouTube">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.google.android.youtube">
<meta property="al:web:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkN7P08_oYM&amp;feature=applinks">

<meta property="og:type" content="video">
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/MkN7P08_oYM?autohide=1&amp;version=3">
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/v/MkN7P08_oYM?autohide=1&amp;version=3">
  <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <meta property="og:video:width" content="1280">
  <meta property="og:video:height" content="720">
```